# Awaiting Dexie query returns is promise when wrapper function is invoked from VueJS component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, promise, dexie

This most likely doesn't have anything to do with VueJS but I'm mentioning it because it's the environment that I am using.

I'm new to IndexedDB and decided to go with Dexie to remove a lot of the complexity. I've started off with creating a very simple database with a simple `where` query. All of Dexie's functions are return promises so inside my Vue component I have the queries wrapped inside an async/await component method.

When I go to invoke the function however, the wrapper function returns a promise rather than awaiting the Dexie query. If I `console.log` the query or assign the query's return value to a component variable the await works, just not when I use the function's return value directly.

This is most likely some misunderstanding that I have with promises that I'm overlooking, but why is my function returning a promise even though I'm awaiting the Dexie query?

```js
// vue route
{
  ...
  beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
      const _db = new Dexie('TestDb')
      _db.version(1).stores({
        people: '++id,name,age'
      })

  Vue.prototype.$_db = _db

  next ()
}
```

```
// vue component template
...
<div>
  {{ getPeople('Pearl') }}
</div>
...
```

```
  // vue component script
  ...
  mounted () {
    this.$_db.people.add({ name: 'Mr. Krabs', age: '75' })
    this.$_db.people.add({ name: 'Pearl', age: '17' })
  },

  async getPeople (name) {
    console.log(await this.$_db.people.where({
      name: name
    }).first()
    )

    return await this.$_db.people.where({
      name: name
    }).first()
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because `async` functions always return a promise.  From the MDN [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function):

> Async functions always return a promise. If the return value of an async function is not explicitly a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise.

Statements that you use `await` on don't do this:

> Await expressions suspend progress through an async function... The resolved value of the promise is treated as the return value of the await expression

So when you log such a statement, you see the value.  But if you return that value and log it, it will have been wrapped in that implicit promise.

Comment: So you would need to await the wrapper function again to unwrap the promise, which can't be done from within the Vue component template. Also, the Vue render is synchronous so asynchronous code can't be called from it which would make sense. So they only way would be to use assign the return value to a component variable and use that inside the template? (Source: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/render-async-method-result-in-template/36505/3)

Comment: Yeah, that all sounds right.  Plus awaiting in the template would be ugly even if it did work.  It's always good to keep the business logic in the controller (component instance) when possible